# How good is using a JavaScript function to print an email address for preventing spam?

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention, email-spam

Something I've recently done on a few sites I've developed for is to create an included JavaScript function which prints an email address based off of an argument. An example below:

**`/index.html`**

```
...
<head>
<script src="/script/main.js></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<p><script>printEmail('info');</script></p>
...
```

**`/script/main.js`**

```
function printEmail(a) {
    document.write('<a href="mailto:' + a + '@domain.com">' + a + '@domain.com</a>');
}
```

The thought process that I have is that the relatively small script *should* help deter spambots by not including the email address in full anywhere in the source code. The only place it becomes readable is through the rendering engine.

So is it secure? Also, how secure is it compared to other prevention methods?

Answer (score 2):

If it renders to the page on page load, I don't think this would do anything, since the spam bots would wait for the page to load anyways and then grab the emails.

If you make a user action required, like hovering over the email to reveal the full email, at which point the javascript prints it out, I think that would be more effective, and I've seen things like that in use on pages before.

Comment: So I guess a secondary question there would be are spambots affected by the email not being in the source, because the source doesn't contain the link at all. Or, do they look at a rendered output and try to use regex to find things that match certain delimiters such as having an @ symbol followed by text and a period? Or do they simply tab through a page trying to find a link to click that opens an email protocol handler?

Comment: @DarkWolffe: From personal experience, obscuring or not having the email address in the source deters 90% of spambots written by people who dislike javascript. But the other 10% write their spambots using Phantom.js so they can parse the DOM instead of the source. This number may change as more and more spammers learn this secret.